# Change the structure of data in SAS

Tags: database, loops, sas, format, dataset

I have a set of SAS data in which each individual entry needs to be reassigned to a temporary dataset with only 2 variables: its color and the number. Right now the set is organized into columns like this:

| Black | Gray | Red | White |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 57 | 59 | 60 | 78 |
| 67 | 76 | 81 | 50 |
| 52 | 62 | 47 | 66 |

EDIT:
The code I had set up was something like this, and I changed it with suggestion from answers on here.

```
    data Dataset1new;
    set Dataset1;
    input Color $ Number;
    do i = 1 to *# of array rows*;
        do j = 1 to *# of array columns*;
            Number = Dataset1[i + j - 1];
            Color = vname(Dataset1[i + j - 1]);
    run;
```

I originally thought about using a do statement to iterate over each entry, but am having difficulty setting it up.

Comment: Please update your question to include the code you tried.  Using a DO loop to iterate over an array, outputting records is reasonable way to transpose this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array and loop over every value. Use the name of the variable to identify its color.

```
data want;
    set have;
    array c[*] Black--White;
    
    do i = 1 to dim(c);
        color = vname(c[i]);
        value = c[i];         
        output;
    end;

    keep color value;
run;
```

This is a more generalized way compared to stacking the data four times:

```
data want;
    set have(in=b rename=(black=value))
        have(in=g rename=(gray=value))
        have(in=r rename=(red=value))
        have(in=w rename=(white=value))
    ;

    select;
        when(b) color='Black';
        when(g) color='Gray';
        when(r) color='Red';
        when(w) color='White';
        otherwise;
    end;

    keep color value;
run;
```

```
color   value
Black   57
Gray    59
Red     60
White   78
Black   67
Gray    76
Red     81
White   50
Black   52
Gray    62
Red     47
White   66
```

Answer (score 3):

If you had a variable (or set of variables) that uniquely identified the observations you could use PROC TRANSPOSE.

Let's add a ROW variable to your example so we can demonstrate.

```
data have;
  row+1;
  input Black Gray Red White ;
cards;
57 59 60 78
67 76 81 50
52 62 47 66
;

proc transpose data=have out=want(rename=(col1=Number)) name=Color;
 by row;
run;
```

Results

```
Obs    row    Color    Number

  1     1     Black      57
  2     1     Gray       59
  3     1     Red        60
  4     1     White      78
  5     2     Black      67
  6     2     Gray       76
  7     2     Red        81
  8     2     White      50
  9     3     Black      52
 10     3     Gray       62
 11     3     Red        47
 12     3     White      66
```